# Hyperledger Fabric - why can I query an other Orgs implicit PDC

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

So I have an implicit PDC at `Org1` and want to query it with `Org2` (get the real data value, not just the hash)

I set up the fabric test network and used `Org1` to write something in its own implicit PDC.

Then I used `Org2` to query it ... and got a result - but how?

Shouldn't be the implicit PDC private to `Org1` and only to `Org1` ... I did not change any Endorsement Policy etc.

Did I misunderstand the idea behind implicit PDCs and do I need to secure them with state-based Endorsement Policy and checks before queries just like public data?

I hope someone can clear that up for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend reading the hyperledger fabric documentation around implicit private collections here https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/private-data-arch.html#implicit-private-data-collections
as it looks like it confirms the behaviour you see